# How to make readerForUpdating.readValue() not to override non null values?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following two classes :

```
public class Simple {

    String a;
    String b;
    SubSimple subSimple;
}

public class SubSimple {

    String a;
    String b;
}
```

What changes can I do to following objectMapper so that non null values are not updated to null :

```
        Simple simple = new Simple();
        simple.setA("0a");
        simple.setSubSimple(new SubSimple());
        simple.getSubSimple().setA("00a");

        String json = "{\"b\" : \"b\", \"subSimple\" : {\"b\" : \"b\"}}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false);


        simple = objectMapper.readerForUpdating(simple).readValue(json);

        System.out.println("simple : " + simple);
```

Current output :

> simple : Simple{a='0a', b='b', subSimple=SubSimple{a='null', b='b'}}

Required :

> simple : Simple{a='0a', b='b', subSimple=SubSimple{a='00a', b='b'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonMerge` annotation:

```
class Simple {

    String a;
    String b;

    @JsonMerge
    SubSimple subSimple;
}
```

or enable it on `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` instance:

```
objectMapper.setDefaultMergeable(Boolean.TRUE);
```